# lg g4 can't find gnustl_shared when using system load in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am loading an ndk module dependent on `libgnustl_shared.so`

I am calling both `mylib.so` and `gnustl_shared` using:

```
System.load("/data/data/package/files/libgnustl_shared.so");
System.load("/data/data/package/files/mylib.so");
```

from an external package, due to product requirements (and not from jniLibs - loadlibrary)

It works like a charm on every device however on lg g4 armv8 `liba.so` can't find `libgnustl_shared`. It's works fine on other armv8 phones.

How can it happen ?
Does any one know how to solve this issue in a generic\spesific way ?

Comment: I fixed some obvious typos. The big question is - where is your Files directory on that LG G4? I assume that your APK extracts the libraries to the standard directory. Verify that its full path is correct.

Comment: I did, both files exist in the file system in the correct path. And the error occurs when the application trys to load the second lib

Comment: You mean, there is no error for `System.load("/data/data/package/files/libgnustl_shared.so")`, but `System.load("/data/data/package/files/liba.so")` failed after that?

Comment: Yes. And only on lg g4. Tryed the same code on Nexus 5x which is also armv8 and it works fine. And off course on previous systems

Comment: Maybe this device has libgnustl_shared.so in the system/lib folder, and the version there is not compatible with yours?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer thanks to Alex Cohn

LG G4 devices have libstlport.so in the system/lib64 folder. this lib is another c++ helper run-time. described in :
http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

when calling system.load() to libgnustl_shared.so, the device called libstlport from lib64 instead of the path specified. since the jni module isn't built on libstlport and it has different code inside mylib.so couldn't handle the situation

solution:

1. compile the jni libs with gnustl_static

   - pros : genarates one .so and can be called onces
   - cons: if you have more than one .so dependent on gnu, it can cause a memory       leak
2. call both libgnustl_shared and the compiled library (mylib.so) from the scope of the main application, and not from the scope of an external library. 
   i.e.:

   System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
   System.loadLibrary("your_native_library");

Comment: Sincerely, I didn't understand the second solution.

Comment: I am loading the libraries in an external package. If they are loaded explicitly (system.load) from the main app and not from the external package the bug does not happen.